# Output a pandas DataFrame in Django with dynamic shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have a pandas DataFrame that has different columns based on a query that generate this DataFrame in the backend.

To output it in Django, an easy approach is to use `.to_html()` method, but it wouldn't work for my use case as I need to make multiple adjustments to the table properties in the template.

Is there a way to output it dynamically?

I thought I can send two copies to Template, one with `.to_dict()` method to use for generating headers and one with `to_dict(orient='records')` to use for generating the table, but it doesn't work as expected.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1,2,3,4],
    'col2': ['A','B', 'C', 'D']
})

context = {
    'df_dict': df.to_dict(),
    'df_rec': df.to_dict(orient='records')
}
```

And in the HTML template:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for key, value in df_dict.items %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for rec in df_rec %}
        <tr>
            {% for ii in rec %}
                <td>{{ rec.ii }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Table renders with correct number of rows, but nothing in the table renders correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a `.items` call in the template:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for key, value in df_dict.items %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for rec in df_rec %}
        <tr>
            {% for i2, k2 in rec.items %}
                <td>{{ k2 }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```